# Stabbing muscles when flexed and when relaxed

Tags: muscles

Just a random question, would a sharp object pierce your muscle more(stabbed with the same amount of force) when the muscle is flexed or when relaxed?

Comment: I would say that it would depend largely on the muscle.

Comment: lets say any large muscle, abdominals, hamstrings, shoulder, etc @RoryM
Edit: or are you talking about the muscle density?

Comment: Depends on the stabbing force and how sharp the object is.

Comment: I suppose in theory the density of the tissue has increased during contraction if you stab in the middle so (preparing for a possible physics disaster) that would mean less penetration for constant force from an identical object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if we look in *very basic* detail at how muscle contraction works within a myofibril of the sarcomere:

[image: Animation of muscle contractions]

<sup>N.b. this isn't on a loop and only plays through seven times</sup>

The red lines represent actin filaments whilst the blue lines represent myosin filaments.  During muscle contraction the filaments move over each other:

[image: Relaxed myofibril]

[image: Partially Contracted myofibril]

[image: (Over)Contracted myofibril]

As shown in the above diagrams the "more contracted" a muscle is then the smaller the size of the H zone (the area where there are *just* myosin filaments).

So if we consider a penetrating impact that went through a plethora of identically aligned sarcomeres (obviously this is not the case in nature) then we could presume that (*et ceteris paribus*) the object would not penetrate as deeply into a contracted muscle as it will hit more tissue on its route than in a relaxed muscle.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed and clearly explained answer! Pity i didnt take Bio during high school...interesting stuff